# Django Paypal integration - Rendering button not working when changing language

Tags: django, paypal

I've integrated Paypal to my website and everything worked as expected. However when i added a new language (greek) i got a problem when pressing pay with paypal button. When change back to english everything works and button is rendering with no probs.

The error i got from paypal is:

[image]

Code i'm using:

```
<div id="paypal-button-container">
                        <!--Paypal button will load-->
                </div>

    // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
    paypal.Buttons({
    
        style: {
            color: 'blue',
            shape: 'rect',
            label: 'pay',
            height: 40
        },
    
        // Set up the transaction
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            console.log('kostas');
            console.log(actions);
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: amount,
                    }
                }]
            });
        },
    
        // Finalize the transaction
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                // Show a success message to the buyer
                console.log(details);
                sendData();
                function sendData() {
                    fetch(url, {
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {
                            "Content-type": "application/json",
                            "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify ({
                            orderID: orderID,
                            transID: details.id,
                            payment_method: payment_method,
                            status: details.status,
                        }),
                    })
                .then((response) => response.json())
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Since is the first attempt to work with paypal i would appreciate any help if you can give me any hint on the below error or any idea on how to troubleshoot.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> when i added a new language (greek) i got a problem when pressing pay with paypal button.

You don't show the code you are adding, so it's impossible to say what specifically is triggering the error, but it appears it may be something in the order creation call, which is not the correct place for changing button text.

To change the language of the buttons to something other than the default (auto-detected based on the browser's language), use the `locale` query string parameter on the SDK `src` line.

Here is the documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/customize-sdk/#locale

Comment: Thank you for your comment and sorry for not being more precise. I do not understand why but i've managed to solve the problem by setting amount without decimal i.e. 31 instead 31,00. Weird stuff is that as far as i understood the problem was with the language but i do not know how these two are connected meaning amount and language. When choosing English everything was working with no problem even with the decimal in the amount. FYI i used locale in the script but didn't solve the problem.

Comment: The PayPal API only accepts a period (`.`) as a decimal separator. If you use a comma separator, expect errors and undefined behaviors.

Comment: That was a hint and i went a little bit deeper. Comma is set by django due to L10N and I18N turned on in my `settings.py`. When i set L10N to False and set back amount with decimal everything worked as expected. Thank you for help.